# Regular expression for php 5.1.6

Tags: php, regex

Can someone help me with a regular expression to include

```
A-z a-z 0-9 - _ (space) (dot) < > ( ) ~
```

and exclude other special symbols in ereg function of php 5.1.6?

I am getting too much confused with the escape character backslash and order of things i need to write if it is required. If not possible with ereg u can suggest me any similar function that works.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ereg version :**

```
if (ereg('^[a-zA-Z0-9.<>()~ _-]+$', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
}
```

**Preg version : (after popular demand)**

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.<>()~ _-]+$/', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
}
```

Something like this?

```
# ^[a-zA-Z0-9.<>()~ _-]+$
# 
# Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
# Match a single character present in the list below «[a-zA-Z0-9.<>()~ _-]+»
#    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
#    A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
#    A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
#    A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
#    One of the characters “.<>()~ ” «.<>()~ »
#    The character “_” «_»
#    The character “-” «-»
# Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: Non-escaped `.`, `(` and `)` throw errors in regex, unless `ereg()` allows them?

Comment: ereg - This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: @JamWaffles Unless my tool is wrong, they do not need to be escaped inside a character class.

Comment: @Drewdin OP asked ereg for 5.1.6 so this is ereg.

Comment: You are indeed correct. Even though the OP _asked_ for `ereg()`, it's probably a better idea to recommend them `preg()`. It's a slot in replacement, and is generally a lot better than ereg.

Comment: I like to put the `-` at the beginning of the character class, otherwise if you're not careful you'll misread the class as including any character in the range `_` to `]`.

Comment: preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.<>()~ _-]+$/', $subject)

Comment: preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.<>()~ _-]+$/', $subject) perfectly worked. yes got to know that ereg geting depricated. this community have been very much helpful to me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
[A-Za-z0-9 _.()~<>-]+
```

Here, match all the characters you want (the list inside `[]`). The `+` at the end means 'match one or more of the characters in the set'.

To match a dash (`-`), it *must* come last in the character list otherwise you end up with badly formed regex due to `-` also denoting ranges of characters, like `A-Z` for example.

Concerning your confusion over the escaping of characters, you don't actually need to do it as FailedDev pointed out, providing your characters are inside a character class: `[]`.

Finally, `ereg_*()` is deprecated. Instead, use the [`preg_*()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) functions.

Comment: preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.<>()~ _-]+$/', $subject) perfectly worked. yes got to know that ereg geting depricated. this community have been very much helpful to me. thank you.